# Along Track Distance ATD

Tags: navigation, gnss, rnav

ATD (Along-Track Distance) is used by ATC for certain types of (rare) NON-Radar Separation. I am training as an Air Traffic Controller in the USA. I have been told the only way to know if an aircraft is ATD is to ask the pilot. Once it is determined that the aircraft is using/capable of ATD, I can ask their distance from a fix, and calculate mileage needed achieve separation. FAA Publications clearly state that RNAV (Area Navigation) equipped aircraft have ATD, however, my question is: Can I assume that any aircraft with GNSS/GPS capability is able ATD? My guess is yes. I am unable to find anything that really ties this down. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ask your ATC trainer?